# Running LINUX Mint 18, have an spdif out sound card--no audio

Tags: audio

BRAND NEW LINUX USER:
Mint sees my digital audio out (Digital Output S/PDIF is in the "play sound through" list) when I access the sound app. I choose that option and I get the test pop up. But the tests do not work. 2 year old Gigabyte soundboard with realtek audio. Works fine in Windows--TOS cable from PC to pioneer receiver, receiver to speakers. :

Answer (score 0):

You can install `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` and get better control of which audio output is being used. That will give you a better idea of if your digital audio output is an option.

Please post output of `aplay --list-devices` and `lspci -v`